# Django Releationship between multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

I just need a little help thinking through this, if someone could be so kind.

```
class object_a(models.Model):
  foo = models.blah
  bar = models.blah

class object_b(models.Model):
  foop = models.blah
  barp = models.blah
```

In another model I have a class that I want to have a single relationship with both fields.  For example, in the admin I want a list of both object_a and object_b objects selectable in some sort of relationship.

I know a generic relationship of some sort can do this, I just can't quite get to the end of the though.  all help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [contenttypes framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) provided by Django:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Other(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Then you can create some of your main objects:

```
>>> from myapp.models import object_a, object_b, Other
>>> a = object_a()
>>> a.foo = 'test'
>>> a.bar = 'value'
>>> a.save()
>>> b = object_b()
>>> b.foop = 'random'
>>> b.barp = 'values'
>>> b.save()
```

And then save references to them in `Other` objects:

```
>>> o1 = Other()
>>> o1.content_object = a
>>> o1.save()
>>> o2 = Other()
>>> o2.content_object = b
>>> o2.save()
```

Now if we ask for all the `Other` objects and inspect them:

```
>>> all = Other.objects.all()
>>> all[0].content_object
<object_a: object_a object>
>>> all[0].content_object.foo
u'test'
>>> all[1].content_object
<object_b: object_b object>
>>> all[1].content_object.foop
u'random'
```

By looking at the fields on the `Other` object, we can see how Django stores the generic relations:

```
>>> all[0].content_type
<ContentType: object_a>
>>> all[0].object_id
1
```

When you run the `syncdb` command to install your models, Django creates a unique `ContentType` object for each model. When you use generic relations, you store a foreign key to this content type entry (identifying what type of object is at the other end of the relation), and the unique ID of the model instance. The `generic.GenericForeignKey` field is not stored in the database, but is a wrapper which takes the content type and object ID and retrieves the actual object for you.

Comment: Hi Blair, that certainly clears up how to do this in the API.  In a view that makes total sense.  But is there a way to represent this type or relationship in the admin?  Thanks again.

Comment: Looking at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline, I need (or at least desire) the opposite of this in the admin.  I want essentially a foreignkey field that is made up of the contents of the objects within object_a and object_b